# How do I get the real time audio stream level on android using visualizer?

Tags: java, android

It looks like android.media.audiofx.Visualizer has what I need to do this, but I can't figure out how to actually use it, even after researching it relatively extensively.  I need to get the volume level as a float between 1 and 0(inclusive), how do I do that?

Comment: The speaker's sound level or while playing an audio ?

Comment: The speaker's sound level